# How do you specify which element in a custom component should be the target of a directive?

Tags: angular

I have a custom directive which changes the background color of an element (e.g. `<button hoverColor="green"><button>`), but when used on a custom component, it sets the background color of the custom component's element which results in no visible effect (e.g. `<app-list hoverColor="green"></app-list>`).

I would like the directive to affect a specific element in the component.
How do I specify which element in my custom component should be the target of the directive?

**list.component.html**

```
<fieldset class="checkboxgroup">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <label *ngFor="let item of items">
      <input type="checkbox" [value]="item[valueProperty]" (change)="onChange($event)">
      {{item[displayProperty]}}
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

**hover-color.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[hoverColor]'
})
export class HoverColorDirective {

  private originalColor: string;
  @Input() hoverColor: string; 

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { 
    this.originalColor = this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.setBackgroundColor(this.hoverColor);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.setBackgroundColor(this.originalColor);
  }

  private setBackgroundColor(color: string) {
    this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

}
```

App.component.html

```
<app-list 
    hoverColor="green" 
    [items]="myItems" 
    title="My Custom List" 
    displayProperty="name" 
    valueProperty="age" 
    [(selectedValues)]="selected"></app-list>
```

I'd like to be able to add something like `ngDirectiveTarget` so that the background color affects the `<fieldset/>` element instead of the actual component element `<app-list/>`

```
<fieldset ngDirectiveTarget class="checkboxgroup">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <label *ngFor="let item of items">
      <input type="checkbox" [value]="item[valueProperty]" (change)="onChange($event)">
      {{item[displayProperty]}}
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Picture of issue: http://prnt.sc/e197g9

Comment: A couple of ideas you could try out: Use the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html) decorator from inside the directive to select the element you're targeting. Not sure a directive has a "view", though. ViewChild could be only for components... OR: Since you have a reference to the root DOM element on which the directive is attached (`this.element.nativeElement`), can you *traverse the DOM* starting from this element until you reach the one you're targeting?

Comment: at first you should check dom node in developer tools to check if your style is applied

Comment: I have verified the style is being applied. The issue I have is that I'd like the directive to be extendable and always target the first element inside a template or, if it's a native element such as a button or div, it should set the background-color on that element. I honestly wouldn't have to do anything if the selector element functioned as a div. I just want a universal way to modify the background of any element or template http://prntscr.com/e197g9